# ZF2, doctrine and Authentication

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

I have used doctrine 2 and ZF2.

After login to system, i am using ZF2 authentication class (`Zend\Authentication\Authenticationservie.php` ) and create one identity.

Now my Identity contains some required values of user (which is further useful and can be fetched), but i have one functionality which update user values which are also in identity, so in this case I need to update existing entity values. otherwise i have to relogin to update entity.

How can i achieve this? there is no function available to update existing entity in `Zend\Authentication\Authenticationservie.php`

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 authentication service use a storage container, in wich the identify data is being stored. you can write to this container with `$this->getStorage()->write( $myData )`

so you update the identity with something like this

```
// benutzer entity update 
$benutzer->setSomeMethodSetTo('newValue');

// doctrine update
$entityManager->persist( $benutzer );
$entityManager->flush();

// write updated benutzer to 
$authService = $this->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Authentication\Authentication');
$authService->getStorage()->write( $benutzer );
```